# Value initialization with Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I think I found a strange fringe case:

What I had:

```
class Day constructor(cal: Calendar, refCal: Calendar) {
    val cal: Calendar
    val isBefore: Boolean
    val isAfter: Boolean

    init {
        this.cal = cal.clone() as Calendar
        isBefore = 0 < cal.compareTo(refCal)
        isAfter = 0 > cal.compareTo(refCal)
    }
}
```

I would instantiate this with two dates, one being a reference, and determine if the date is before or after a reference date. However, what I found on execution is that `isBefore` and `isAfter` remained false *in some cases*, independently of what they should be worth, unless I went in step-by-step with the debugger. So, apparently `init` was called not right after the constructor, just delayed enough for my values not to be set?

What I did to resolve it was simply calculate `isBefore` and `isAfter` in getters:

```
class Day constructor(cal: Calendar, refCal: Calendar) {
    val cal: Calendar

    init {
        this.cal = cal.clone() as Calendar
        this.refCal = refCal.clone() as Calendar
    }

    val isBefore: Boolean
        get() { return 0 < cal.compareTo(refCal) }
    val isAfter: Boolean
        get() { return 0 > cal.compareTo(refCal) }
}
```

I'd like to know if my assumption is correct, if there's a way a value can be called before it is initialized with `init` and if so, if there is a way to mitigate this.

---

Call example:

```
fun setDates(refDate: Calendar) {
    val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
    cal.set(refDate.get(Calendar.YEAR), refDate.get(Calendar.MONTH), refDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 0, 0, 0)

    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY)
    val monday = Day(cal, refDate)
    //...
```

Comment: There's nothing apparently wrong with this code, the calls in the initializer block happen at construction time, before you can read the values of the properties externally.

Comment: How do you call it? How do you create the Calendar objects that you pass to the constructor?

Comment: @user2340612: Added example

Comment: What is variable `calendar`, that you use to set `cal`'s fields?

Comment: Can you construct a minimal test case?

Comment: The code in `init()` is compiled as part of the constructor. There are possibilities to observe uninitialized values, but these mostly happen in case of subclassing (when a method overridden in a subclass is called before the subclass constructor has finished running) or when there are dependencies between initializers.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Will do by tonight.

Comment: @user2340612 It's it's supposed to be `refDate`. Sorry for the confusion. Edited the example.

Comment: This looks so much like Java. Why are you using the `init` function anyway?

Comment: Oh, and I do zero the times. Forgot to add that in.

Comment: I can't replicate the error in a minimal test case yet. Which tells me I've got something wrong elsewhere. Will keep at that portion of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know the `init` block will be executed within the primary constructor, so your original class `Day` should be fine. You could just remove the `init` block and assign the values directly with the property's declaration though.

I see just 2 problems, one is:

> However, what I found on execution is that isBefore and isAfter
>   remained false in some cases

That wouldn't be a surprise at all if `cal.compareTo(refCal)` returned `0`. 
Or if the value of `refCal` changed between the execution of the 2 lines

```
isBefore = 0 < cal.compareTo(refCal)
isAfter = 0 > cal.compareTo(refCal)
```

Second problem is your second `Day` implementation, when you declare a getter for the property

```
val isBefore: Boolean
    get() { return 0 < cal.compareTo(refCal) }
```

you're comparing the value each time you read that property, this means that `isBefore`'s value could very easily change within the same `Day`instance, if the value of `refCal` property changes. If you want just to read the value of `refCal` and assign `isBefore` accordingly you should do that when initializing the property, within `init` block or within declaration (you could also omit the type and use `>` operator directly):

```
class Day constructor(cal: Calendar, refCal: Calendar) {
    private val cal = cal.clone() as Calendar
    val isBefore = cal > refCal
    val isAfter = cal < refCal
}
```

And maybe add property like `val isEqual = !isBefore && !isAfter` because those 2 are not mutually exclusive.

**Update**

I just checked with Kotlin 1.2.30, Intellij's Kotlin plugin allows you to see the bytecode of the compile Kotlin class (the action is called "Show Kotlin Bytecode"). The code you put in the `init` block is indeed executed within the primary constructor. For instance this class:

```
class Day(cal: Calendar)  {

    val cal: Calendar

    init {
        this.cal = cal.clone() as Calendar
    }
}
```

Compiles this constructor:

```
  // access flags 0x1
  public <init>(Ljava/util/Calendar;)V
    @Lorg/jetbrains/annotations/NotNull;() // invisible, parameter 0
   L0
    ALOAD 1
    LDC "cal"
    INVOKESTATIC kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;)V
   L1
    LINENUMBER 3 L1
    ALOAD 0
    INVOKESPECIAL java/lang/Object.<init> ()V
   L2
    LINENUMBER 8 L2
    ALOAD 0
    ALOAD 1
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/util/Calendar.clone ()Ljava/lang/Object;
    DUP
    IFNONNULL L3
    NEW kotlin/TypeCastException
    DUP
    LDC "null cannot be cast to non-null type java.util.Calendar"
    INVOKESPECIAL kotlin/TypeCastException.<init> (Ljava/lang/String;)V
    ATHROW
   L3
    CHECKCAST java/util/Calendar
    PUTFIELD Day.cal : Ljava/util/Calendar;
   L4
    RETURN
   L5
    LOCALVARIABLE this LDay; L0 L5 0
    LOCALVARIABLE cal Ljava/util/Calendar; L0 L5 1
    MAXSTACK = 5
    MAXLOCALS = 2
```

As you can see the `Calendar.clone` is called there, so you can treat the `init` the same way as you would with a constructor in Java.

If you don't have a primary constructor, e.g.:

```
class Day {
    constructor(cal: Calendar)
    constructor()

    val cal: Calendar

    init {
        this.cal = Calendar.getInstance()
    }
}
```

2 constructors are created and the code of the `init` block is executed in each one of them.

```
  // access flags 0x1
  public <init>(Ljava/util/Calendar;)V
    @Lorg/jetbrains/annotations/NotNull;() // invisible, parameter 0
   L0
    ALOAD 1
    LDC "cal"
    INVOKESTATIC kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;)V
   L1
    LINENUMBER 4 L1
    ALOAD 0
    INVOKESPECIAL java/lang/Object.<init> ()V
   L2
    LINENUMBER 10 L2
    ALOAD 0
    INVOKESTATIC java/util/Calendar.getInstance ()Ljava/util/Calendar;
    DUP
    LDC "Calendar.getInstance()"
    INVOKESTATIC kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics.checkExpressionValueIsNotNull (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;)V
    PUTFIELD Day.cal : Ljava/util/Calendar;
   L3
    RETURN
   L4
    LOCALVARIABLE this LDay; L0 L4 0
    LOCALVARIABLE cal Ljava/util/Calendar; L0 L4 1
    MAXSTACK = 4
    MAXLOCALS = 2

  // access flags 0x1
  public <init>()V
   L0
    LINENUMBER 5 L0
    ALOAD 0
    INVOKESPECIAL java/lang/Object.<init> ()V
   L1
    LINENUMBER 10 L1
    ALOAD 0
    INVOKESTATIC java/util/Calendar.getInstance ()Ljava/util/Calendar;
    DUP
    LDC "Calendar.getInstance()"
    INVOKESTATIC kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics.checkExpressionValueIsNotNull (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;)V
    PUTFIELD Day.cal : Ljava/util/Calendar;
   L2
    RETURN
   L3
    LOCALVARIABLE this LDay; L0 L3 0
    MAXSTACK = 4
    MAXLOCALS = 1
```